# Getting multiple 404 for Copy_of_Facebook_Ad_Untitled_Design_1.png

Tags: shopify

I am getting multiple 404 error for Copy_of_Facebook_Ad_Untitled_Design_1.png.
Can anybody please tell me what this .png file is for? How to resolve this?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the 404 http error comes when the requested asset or file is not found in server. Looking at the console image I would say somewhere in your theme that particular cdn link of the image has been used which is not a valid link.

With out looking the code or knowing the theme name it's difficult to say what it is for. If you are not sure where it has been used then search for the file in your code base and remove it or provide a correct cdn link

Comment: Thanks. Got it solved. The cdn link was wrong but not sure how it happened as I did not touch anything in that corner.